# Displaying image as links using php and mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am creating a photo gallery using PHP and MYSQL. I want the mages and the captions under them to have a hyperlinks on them. The hyperlink for both the image and the caption under it will go to the same web page. How do I get images and their captions to display on a web page using php and mysql? It's important that the images and the captions have links on them. [Image of the PhpMymin database and table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M305R.png)
This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
mysql_connect ("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db ("display_images");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1");


echo "<table>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>"; ?> 
    echo '<a href="'$row ["imagelink"].'"><img src="img/'.echo $row ["images1"].'" width="150" height="150" alt=""> <br>'

echo $row ["caption"] </a>' </td>; echo "</td>";

    echo "</tr>";
  }

echo "</table>";



?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: pay close attention to your quoted and unquoted strings; check the difference between html to be echo'd and code to be executed.  this is extremely important to learn immediately.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try below code for your need , In your code you are not using proper enquotes for html code and php variable ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
   mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
   mysql_select_db("display_images"); // Please check with your database name
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1");

   echo "<table>";

   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
   {
       $image_link = $row['imagelink'];
       $image_path = $row['image1'];
       echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td>";
       echo "<a href=".$image_link."><img src=".$image_path." width='150' height='150' alt='' /> <br>";
       echo $row['caption']."</a>"; 
       echo "</td>";
       echo "</tr>";
   }

   echo "</table>";

?>
```

I hope this will help you , Feel free to comment.

Comment: Can you please tell me what error you are getting ? Or can you send the inspect element html code for this page ?

Comment: The image is not displaying on webpage.

Comment: I'm getting a Parse error on line 16 when I run the code. Line 16 is the line that is echoing out the link and the image. The following is the error message I keep getting: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting. Please help.

Comment: Please try my editted answer , please upvote my answer if it works , thanks.

Comment: I am glad , i could help you :)